# vscode opens a white screen when running in super-user mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, root, ubuntu-20.04

I've installed vscode on my ubuntu and I'm trying to run it with root privileges.
I understand there is a problem with this version and root privileges.
I use this command from my terminal:

sudo code /my_fils --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox

but when running it vscode opens a blank and white screen with super-user definition on top but with nothing else.
I know there was a problem with this configuration and I found this issue in this link :
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59#_progress-for-electron-sandbox-support

I've tried the following but the outcome is the same:

sudo chown root /chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 /chrome-sandbox

running vscode without the root privilege works.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and my vscode version is 1.70.2

is there a workaround for it?

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems to be an issue try 1.65.x it might run. encountered the same when installing a fluent theme.

Checkout : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146847

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot. I downgraded my VSCode to 1.65. No need to change owner or permission.

Follow these steps -

1. Uninstall vscode by running below command

   ```
   sudo apt purge code
   ```
2. Download vs 1.65 from here -
   https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.65.2/linux-deb-x64/stable
3. Double-click and install
4. Once installed, launch vscode from the code repository( considering I am at my code repo directory so using ".")

   ```
   sudo code . --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox
   ```